# ActiveRecord serialize coder argument not seeming to work

Tags: ruby, serialization, activerecord

I have an `Entry` class that has a `Charge` attribute that I want to instantiate from a string as a `Charge` object when read from the DB:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :charge, Charge
end

class Charge
  # Reading from the db as a string
  def self.load(str)
    str.nil? ? nil : new(str)
  end

  # Writing to the db as a string
  def self.dump(chg)
    chg.nil? ? nil : chg.to_s
  end
end
```

This works fine:

```
ent = Entry.find(1)
ent.charge.class => Charge
```

However, AR is issuing a deprecation warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing the coder as positional argument is deprecated and will be  removed in Rails 7.2.
> Please pass the coder as a keyword argument:

> serialize :charge, coder: Byr::Charge

But when I do this, AR fails to deserialize the attribute as a Charge but just returns it as a String from the DB.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :charge, coder: Charge
end
```

```
ent = Entry.find(1)
ent.charge.class => String
```

Am I missing something, or is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Hi Daniel, what version of Rails are you running?

Comment: This is a non-rails command-line app using AR 7.0.8.

Comment: Can you please confirm the version you'r using? 7.0.8 does not have that deprecation warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that the serialized attribute `charge` is of the `Charge` class, you need to specify the `:type` parameter in the serializer call. Also, the `load` method should return a new empty object when `nil`.

The change in the method signature allows you to define separate coder and type classes. This way, your code can load/dump with a certain class and have the attribute be of a different class.

```rb
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :charge, coder: Charge, type: Charge
end

class Charge
  def self.load(str)
    str.nil? ? new(nil) : new(str)
  end
end
```

For more information, see:

- [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::ClassMethods.serialize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize)
- [rails/rails#47463](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/47463)

Comment: After making the above change, I stil get the charge attribute as a String.  It also looks from the documentation you linked to that the type argument is not needed if you have a coder except to raise an exception if the value returned by the coder is not of the given type, but I'll admit it's not all that clear.  Thanks for the suggestion though, R. Sierra.

Comment: Oh sorry, my answer was based on AR v7.1.2

Comment: @DanielDoherty I updated the answer, please see if it solves the issue.

Comment: R. Sierra, thanks for the suggestions.  However, it is still not working.  I did manage to look at the code you linked to though and it appears that it is not picking up the 'coder: Charge' option as the 'class_name_or_coder' at around line 108 of the attribute_methods/serialization.rb file.  It's there in the options parameter, but the code seems to ignore that.  If I use this:  `serialize :charge, Charge, type: Charge` it works, but not `serialize :charge, coder: Charge, type: Charge`.  Is this perhaps a bug in AR?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the AR Github source for the line you mentioned?

Comment: R. Sierra, it turns out that I was using 7.0.8 but looking at docs for a later version, so it turns out your instincts were right.  I figured this out by submitting an issue on rails where it all go cleared up, but I am accepting your answer with the proviso that it applies to versions later than 7.0.8.  Thanks for taking the time on this.  Sorry for the noise.